# Is this conditional probability or independent events?

Tags: probability, problem-solving

Jack and Ben have been tracking their success rate of converting goals in their rugby games. Jack converts $70\%$ of his goals and Ben converts $60\%$. At a recent home game, both get a kick, but only one converts his goal. What is the probability that it was Ben?

I tried using the conditional probability formula and it didn't work. Someone suggested using the addition formula $P(J \text{ xor } B) = P(J) + P(B) - 2P(J \text{ and } B)$ and I thought the answer it gave seemed correct ($0.46$) but the answer at the back of the textbook says otherwise.

Comment: You *use* the formula to get the answer; it is not the answer by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start right after they both get a kick, since that even doesn't have any numbers associated with it.  At this point, there's a 70% chance that Jack converts his kick and a (presumably independent) 60% chance that Ben converts his.  So the four possible outcomes, each with its probability, are as follows:

- Both convert their kicks: $0.7 \times 0.6 = 0.42$,
- Jack converts his but not Ben: $0.7 \times 0.4 = 0.28$,
- Ben converts his but not Jack: $0.3 \times 0.6 = 0.18$,
- Neither converts their kick: $0.3 \times 0.4 = 0.12$.

(Notice that these four probabilities add up to 100%, as they should.)

So far, it's been independent events, but now we bring in conditional probability.  We are told that one and only converts their kick, so the first and last possibility are ruled out.  We're conditioning on an event with $0.28 + 0.18 = 0.46$ probability, and we're looking at the event with $0.18$ probability, so we divide to get the conditional probability: $0.18 \div 0.46 \approx 0.39$ (or you could give an exact rational answer).

This is the same result as @Tortar gave, but perhaps the added detail will help you understand it.

Comment: By the way, the $0.46$ that you got with your XOR formula is the same $0.46$ that I got from $0.28 + 0.18$.  So the XOR formula was not wrong.  But this is still just the denominator of the final answer.  You're not being asked the probability that exactly one kick is converted; you're being asked a probability *given* that exactly one kick is converted.

Comment: hmmm what is the xor probability formula? I searched it up and nothing came up. Why do you times the ( and ) by 2? ie $2( and )$ 

Also, is $P(A and B)$ the same as $P(B and A)$?

Comment: The ‘xor formula’ isn't the name of the formula; I just meant the addition formula involving XOR that you used in your question.  There's also an addition formula involving inclusive OR that leaves out the factor of $2$.  But I prefer to list possibilities (as in my answer) rather than to keep track of the formulas.  And yes, $A$ AND $B$ is the same as $B$ AND $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the formula for *exclusive or*, and since $B$ and $J$ are independent:$$\def\P{\mathop{\sf P}}\P(J\text{ xor } B)~{=\P(J)+\P(B)-2\P(J\text{ and }B)\\=\P(B)+\P(J)-2\P(B)\P(J)\\=\P(B)(1-\P(J))+\P(J)(1-\P(B))}$$

However, you *use* this formula to get the answer; it is not the answer by itself.

The *conditional* probability you seek is: $$\P(B\mid J\text{ xor } B)~{=\dfrac{\P(B\text{ and not }J)}{\P(J\text{ xor } B)}\\=\dfrac{\P(B)(1-\P(J))}{\P(B)(1-\P(J))+\P(J)(1-\P(B))}\\=\dfrac{\P(B)-\P(B)\P(J))}{\P(B)+\P(J)-2\P(B)\P(J)}}$$

Comment: is conditional the same a dependent in probability?

Comment: Im wondering how you got $\frac{( and not )}{( xor )}$ I believe it is conditional probability formula? Why is the numerator like so? Is it just part of the formula?

Comment: $B\text{ and }(J\text{ xor }B)$ equals $B\text{ and not }J$. @user71207

Answer (score 0):

Based on bayes' theorem:

$$P(Ben \ converted \ a \ kick \ |  \ both \ get \ a \ kick  \ and    \ one  \ converted  \ it ) = \frac{60\% \cdot 30\%}{60\% \cdot 30\% + 70\% \cdot 40\%}$$

Comment: Thanks, I've never heard of Bayes Theorem but it seems to work and I'll look into it

Comment: nothing, you're welcome